# How to build a list of all the wfs (well-formed sentences)?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

let $A1$, $A2$, $A3$...$An$ be an enumeration of all the wfs of L, I am trying to construct a method that allows to build this list. This challenge appears in the demonstration of **Proposition 2.21** of the book [Logic for Mathematicians](https://books.google.it/books?id=TO098EjWT38C&pg=PA41) of Alan G. Hamilton:

[image]

Comment: I need to build an algorithm with which I can generate all the possible wfs.

Comment: You have to manage a double-infinite list like, that used by the standard proof of the [enumerability of rationals](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Rational_Numbers_are_Countably_Infinite). The infinite matrix is made according to the lenght of the formula: 1st row: lenght 1: only sentential letters; 2nd row: lenght 2: only negated sentential letters, etc. But each row is infinite: thus you need a zig-zag approach the move on one step on each row.